# Javascript recursive setTimeout doesn't use full final JSON returned

Tags: javascript, jquery, recursion

I am making recursive calls to a URL until it returns success or has hit the max tries limit.  Here is the relevant code, (minified, so to speak):

```
function doSomething(numRetries) {
    $.post('someURL', {retry: numRetries},
        function (data) {
            if (data.value == 1) {
                displayResults(data.message, data.value);
            } else if (data.value == "retry") {
                setTimeout( function() { doSomething(data.retries) }, 1000);
            } else {
                displayResults(data.message, data.value);
            }
        },
        "json"
    );
}
```

IFF the **first** call to sumeURL returns data.value == 1, it executes displaySuccess.  Similarly, if it returns another value (e.g. 0), it will displayFailure() successfully.

The problem lies in the recursive part.  After it kicks off the retries, it *does* call doSomething() again with an incrementing retries value, but any return data after that is not used.

So when my retry timeout inside someURL is 3, for example, I can see in firebug:

```
post('someURL', 0) returns JSONified (value = "retry", retries = 1)
post('someURL', 1) returns JSONified (value = "retry", retries = 2)
post('someURL', 2) returns JSONified (value = 0, error = "Display this error!")
```

but an alert() inside displayFailure indicates that error = [undefined], even though value = 0 (not "retry").  Firebug indicates proper JSON parsing is occurring.

**EDIT** modify the doSomething to be a more accurate reflection of reality, though the changes shouldn't introduce any uncertainty, and by request, here are the actual return values from the post calls:

```
{"success":"retry","retryCount":"1"}
{"success":"retry","retryCount":"2"}
{"success":0,"errormsg":"The request is taking longer than expected, but should be completed soon.  Please try again in 15 minutes."}
```

and lastly here is a minified displayResults():

```
function displayResults(text, status) {
    $('#dispElem').queue(function(next) {   //this is so that fades happen around the text update, not before/during it; there may be better ways to do this
        $('#dispElem').html(text);
        if (status == 1) {
            $('#dispElem').addClass("success");
        } else {
            // hide and show random elements
        }
        next();
    }).fadeIn().queue(function(next) { //scroll to bottom; next(); });
}
```

Comment: Nothing jumps out at me as obviously wrong. Perhaps you could post your displayFailure() function too?

Comment: Either there's some issue with the property name you're trying to access, or there's some issue within the `displayFailure()` function. Either way, the issue can't be known from the code in the question. Please post the `displayFailure()` function, and the raw JSON data received.

Comment: I don't believe the error lies in this piece of code. probably in your displayFailiure function.

Comment: Note that this is not really "recursive".  The ".post()" callback is asynchronous, as is the "setTimeout()" handler. There's only ever one activation of the "doSomething()" function at any given time. A "recursive" function is one that calls itself *directly*, so that there are multiple activations nested one atop the other.

Comment: Fair point re: not true recursion.  I'm away from work, so I'll update with as much additional information as I can tomorrow. Not that there's any real secret sauce here, but I still need to protect the identity of the page I'm working on.

I appreciate the comments pointing me in the direction of re-evaluating my other code.  It's frustrating, but good to know that _maybe_ I'm not doing anything wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

Arrrgh.

The worst scenario of all - an uppercase/lowercase mistake I just kept overlooking until forced to retype to minify.

Thanks, all, for the comments and making me recomb it, with a finer tooth, so to speak.